# Сложный SQL запрос из нескольких таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Знатоки, приветствую. Есть три таблицы вида:

### Table 1 - Cards

Clientid | FIO

### Table 2 - Clients

Cardid | Clientid | Cardnumber

### Table 3 - Transactions

Cardid | Date | Summa

Необходимо написать SQL запрос возвращающий номер карты и сумму всех транзакций по определенному клиенту за весь период с разбивкой по каждой карте.

Т.е. вбиваем только FIO, а получить должны сумму всех транзакций с разбивкой по картам клиента.
Желательно на MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не назвал бы этот запрос сложным :)

```
SELECT Cards.Cardnumber, SUM(Transactions.Summa)
FROM Cards
LEFT JOIN Clients ON Clients.Clientid = Cards.Clientid
LEFT JOIN Transactions ON Cards.Cardid = Transactions.Cardid
WHERE Clients.FIO = <FIO>
GROUP BY Cards.Cardnumber
```

Наименования таблиц неправильны (возможно, это опечатка): Table 1 должен называться Clients, а Table 2 Cards.

PS: запрос не проверял.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, в наименовании таблиц опечатался, извиняюсь. Запрос отрабатывает именно так, как нужно, благодарю. Действительно, всё оказалось просто и элегантно.